# Указатель на больший тип переменной

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

И так.
Есть два массива:

```
int arr_int[3] = {0x1122, 0x3344, 0x5566};  
char *arr_char;
```

Я хочу, что-бы arr_char[0] был равен 0х22, arr_char[1]=0x11, arr_char[2]=0x44, arr_char[3]=0x33 и т.д.
Но это все надо сделать работой с памятью, а не for'ами, присваиваниями и сравнениями.

Можно ли это сделать? И как?
Я пытался вот таким способом, но что-то я делаю не так:

```
arr_char = arr_int;
```

Такое присваивание не правильное, так как под arr_int выделено три ячейки по два байта, а под arr_char выделено шесть ячеек по одному байту, хотя в памяти они должны выглядеть одинаково мне кажется...

Что же делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете проделать эту операцию без присваиваний и некоторого вида циклов. Во-первых, объекты типа `int` могут занимать, например, 4 байта. Поэтому ваш целочисленный массив, фактически выглядит как

```
int arr_int[3] = {0x00001122, 0x00003344, 0x00005566};
```

То есть его размер будет в этом случае составлять 12 байтов, а не 6, как вы предполагаете.

Более того в зависимости от платформы числа могут храниться либо таким образом, когда в младших адресах располагаются младшие значащие цифры, либо, напротив, когда в младших адресах хранятся старшие значащие цифры.

Так что вам в любом случае придется делать присваивание каждому элементу символьного массива некоторого значения из целочисленного массива.

EDIT: После изменения вашего вопроса и с учетом того, что целые числа занимают всего лишь два байта и хранятся в памяти соответственно начиная с младших цифр в младших адресах памяти, то можно написать

```
arr_char = ( char * )arr_int;
```

Comment: Я понимаю.   
Но просто теоретически, давайте допустим, что в моей системе int 2 байта, а char один байт. И данные хранятся как big-endian.  
Можно ли тогда сделать то, что я пытаюсь делать?

Comment: @MichaelVaysman Вы объявили массив char. В него в любом случае что-то надо занести. То есть это отдельный участок памяти, который должен быть чем-то заполнен. Так что без присваивания не обойтись.

Comment: хорошо :) Давайте представим, что это не массив, а указатель: char *arr_char;

Comment: Возможно, ТС хотел `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman: Тогда подправьте вопрос, это кардинально меняет ситуацию.

Comment: Исправил. Прошу прощения. Вы правы, при определении массива участок памяти уже выделен...

Answer (score 0):

После изменения char arr_char[6] на char *arr_char - все заработало как я и предпологал.
Спасибо @Vlad from Moscow и @VladD за помощь!